# Keras Trained VGG error

Tags: python, keras, theano, vgg-net

I have followed [this](https://gist.github.com/baraldilorenzo/07d7802847aaad0a35d3) to load and run a pretrained VGG model. However, I was trying to extract feature maps from hidden layers and trying to replicate results from the "Extracting arbitrary feature maps" section [here](http://blog.christianperone.com/2016/01/convolutional-hypercolumns-in-python/). My code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import theano
from scipy import misc
from PIL import Image
import PIL.ImageOps
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Flatten, Dense, Dropout
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D, ZeroPadding2D
from keras.optimizers import SGD
import numpy as np
from keras import backend as K

def get_features(model, layer, X_batch):
    get_features = K.function([model.layers[0].input, K.learning_phase()], [model.layers[layer].output,])
    features = get_features([X_batch,0])
    return features

def VGG_16(weights_path=None):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1),input_shape=(3,224,224)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))

    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))

    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))

    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))

    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
    model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(1000, activation='softmax'))

    if weights_path:
        model.load_weights("/home/srilatha/Desktop/Research_intern/vgg16_weights.h5")

    return model

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #f="/home/srilatha/Desktop/Research_intern/Data_sets/Data_set_2/FGNET/male/007A23.JPG"
    f="/home/srilatha/Desktop/Research_intern/Data_sets/Cropped_data_set/1/7.JPG"
    image = Image.open(f)
    new_width  = 224
    new_height = 224
    im = image.resize((new_width, new_height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    im=np.array(im)
    im=np.tile(im[:,:,None],(1,1,3))
    #imRGB = np.repeat(im[:, :, np.newaxis], 3, axis=2)
    print(im)
    #print(type(im))
    im = im.transpose((2,0,1))
    im = np.expand_dims(im, axis=0)


    # Test pretrained model
    model = VGG_16('/home/srilatha/Desktop/Research_intern/vgg16_weights.h5')
    sgd = SGD(lr=0.1, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
    model.compile(optimizer=sgd, loss='categorical_crossentropy')
    out = model.predict(im)
    #get_feature = theano.function([model.layers[0].input], model.layers[3].get_output(train=False), allow_input_downcast=False)
    #feat = get_feature(im)
    #get_activations = theano.function([model.layers[0].input], model.layers[1].get_output(train=False), allow_input_downcast=True)
    #activations = get_activations(model, 1, im)
    #plt.imshow(activations)
    #plt.imshow(im)
    features=get_features(model,15,im)
    plt.imshow(features[0][13])
    #out = model.predict(im)
    #plt.plot(out.ravel())
    #plt.show()
    print np.argmax(out)
```

However, I was getting this error:

```
File "VGG_Keras.py", line 98, in <module>
    plt.imshow(features[0][13])
IndexError: index 13 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, next time pls update a cleaner version of your code so that others can help you more easily.

Secondly, modify your function to debug:

```
def get_features(model, layer, X_batch):
    print model.layers[layer]
    print model.layers[layer].output_shape
    get_features = K.function([model.layers[0].input, K.learning_phase()], [model.layers[layer].output,])
    features = get_features([X_batch,0])
    print features.shape
    return features
```

You will find that `features` is actually a `list`:

1. output of `K.function` is list, namely, `get_features` is the result of `[model.layers[layer].output,]`.
2. `get_features[0]` is therefore `model.layers[layer].output` in shape `(1, 256, 56, 56)==>(batch_size, channel, W, H)`
3. `get_features[0][0]` is the feature of the first picture in batch.
4. I believe what you are looking for is `get_features[0][0][13]`.